# Ubuntu 14.10, Compiled or Installed vim-gnome, doesn't paste from stopped vim

Tags: vim, clipboard, compile

I just compiled vim with many many different ways and I can't get it working properly on Ubuntu 14.10.

this is my configure:

```
./configure \
 --enable-pythoninterp \
 --enable-cscope \
 --enable-gui=auto \
 --enable-gtk2-check \
 --enable-gnome-check \
 --with-features=huge \
 --enable-multibyte \
 --with-x 
 --with-compiledby="xx"
```

The problem is it: I can't paste from the system clipboard, that was filled in vim (eg: "+yy), if my vim was stopped once (I put it in background with Ctrl+z). My clipboard is erased and I've to open the vim and copy the text again, very annoying.

What am I missing ?

Also its doesn't work if I install the package vim-gnome either. I think it's a problem with the Ubuntu 14.10

BR

Comment: You know you can do `$ sudo apt-get install vim-gnome`, right?

Comment: Yes but I want to compile with because I want to install the 7.4 version on Ubuntu 10.04.

Comment: The default Vim *is* 7.4 since 14.04. Do you want to install Vim 7.4 on Ubuntu 14.10 or 10.04?

Comment: in both, I'm trying to do the same install process in both systems. For now its for the 14.10 one.

Comment: Then you should add as much background info as possible.

Comment: When you sau "stopped" do you mean you suspended it (Ctrl+Z)?